# Set ip address and stuff on Ubuntu

Tags: lan, ip

how can I set Ip Address, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway, Preferred DNS Server and Alternative DNS Server on Ubuntu 14.04?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open dash and type `Network` and select `Network` under application's lens:

[image]

And set your IP address, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway and other settings as easy as you want: press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between IP address, Subnet Mask and Default Gateway

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open network settings, then select your internet access point using the orange arrow...
[image]
then click "Settings" to configure your advanced internet settings.
[image]

Comment: "How can I set ..." He/She is not asking about "How can I see ..."

Comment: @KasiyA I clearly stated "then click 'Settings' to configure your advanced internet settings."