# How can I change my IP address?

Tags: networking, browser, ip

I want to change my IP address and port to some other values. My idea is to attain anonymity when I browse in the web. Currently I am on a network having static IPs for each system. I know there are web based proxies. But i want to do this configuration specifically in my system. It will be helpful if anyone can teach me if it can be done on terminal as well as GUI.

Comment: here http://askubuntu.com/a/518811/283843

Comment: On a side note, changing your local IP will not achieve anonymity on the web. you might wish to use tor (http://torproject.org )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you are complete unaware of nat ip and main ip. the nat or network ip is the assignation of the local computer done by the router.if you visit the web and then there's nothing to do with your local ip.to know your main ip just google myip and it will come out with many sites showing your main ip which is given by your isp.
to be anonmous i suggest to go to

https://www.torproject.org/

and download tor for your system and  run the software and now google myip and now you will get the differnce in ip.

Answer (score 1):

Most internet users are sitting behind NAT, so it's equal which IP adress you have locally. NAT changes your local IP addres to your routers global IP adress. If you want to change your **local** IP adress see [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html). If you want to anonimize your global IP-Traffic (e.g. WWW,Email) you must use an [anonimizing technology](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2013534/how-and-why-to-surf-the-web-in-secret.html) like VPN, Proxy or TOR.

Answer (score -1):

You can add anonymoux addons for your browser to change the IP for specific sites. It can be added directly by addons option.